# How to create initial zoom on Plotly express bar chart? (categorical)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a categorical axis in plotly express, it contains around 100 different categories. What I want to do is that when I create it, it will be zoomed only on the first 10 categories and then the user will be able to zoom out using the plotly controls. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the x range but treat each category as an integer starting at 0.

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.bar(df,
    x = 'species',
    y = 'sepal_length',
    range_x = [-0.5, 1.5],
    barmode = 'overlay',
                    )
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is using **rangeslider** and **range** on you **xaxis**

Have generated a sample data set where **x** is categorical to demonstrate this.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "category": [
            chr(r % 26 + 65) if r // 26 == 0 else chr(r // 26 + 64) + chr(r % 26 + 65)
            for r in range(100)
        ],
        "value": np.sin(np.linspace(-2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi, 100)),
    }
)


px.bar(df, x="category", y="value").update_layout(
    xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True, xaxis_range=[0, 10]
)
```

[image]